# How to insert data (string array) to h2 database?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, h2

I have array of string in my JPA entity class declared like this

```
private String[] suggestion = new String[3];
```

I insert the data by creating sql file in my **'resource'** folder. How to insert array of string to database using `INSERT INTO .. VALUES (..) ???`

Comment: You can do that by writing multiple insert statement in `data.sql` file. OR Explain how should your table look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this working example with H2 as I have tested it.

First add these properties in application.properties file:

```
# To See H2 Console in Browser:
# http://localhost:8080/h2-console
# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

# ===============================
# DB
# ===============================

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
#jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

# ===============================
# JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Controller Code:

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/test")
    public Person checkTest() {
        System.out.println("PWan");
        return personService.savePerson();
    }

}
```

Service Code:

```
@Service
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public Person savePerson() {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setFullname("Pawan");
        personRepository.save(p);
        return p;

    }

}
```

Repository Code:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>{

    public Person findByfullname(String name);

    public Optional<Person> findById(Long id);

}
```

Please find the below link for reference:

[Spring boot with H2 DB My git](https://github.com/pawantiwari224/MyTestWithH2DB)

Let me know, if there are any issues.

Comment: @pindo, Glad to hear that. Please consider to upvote and accept the answer so that others can find it useful.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer does not show how to actually insert a string array into an h2 database using JPA.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an Application Listener to listen to Context Refreshed Event of spring and override onApplicationEvent() method to insert your data into the database.

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
        public class Bootstrap implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
            //    Array Initialization
            private String[] suggestion = new String[3];

            @Override
            public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
                initData();
            }

            private void initData(){
        //        Loop through array
                for (String item : suggestion){
        //            Insert data using a repository
                }
            }
        }
```

This Event raised when an ApplicationContext gets initialized or refreshed. [Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html) to java doc.

Comment: and where do you think, the suggestion should be populated?

Comment: It depends on where you want to populate suggestions. You can create an entity for the suggestion so spring context will generate the schema. So you can use a Spring data crud repository to persist suggestions. See the comment on the code   //  Insert data using a repository